iOS Swift Array `randomElement` 6% bias on big sample size?
tl;dr doing Swift's Array.randomElement() brings perfect results when testing locally but in production there is a huge bias to the second element in the array and I don't know what to do about it.
Code
We're running a split test for a price offer in our app. We use Array.randomElement() to determine what price to show which is calculated during app launch like
if let coinSide = CoinSide.allCases.randomElement() {
    uploadResult("\(coinSide.rawValue)")
} else {
    // uploaded in case of nil but that never happened so far
}

Results
To verify results, we also send the result to our backend. So far, it's
 tails: 1,898 (53%)
 heads: 1,675 (47%)
(total: 3,573)

Analysis
Performing a Binomial Test (n = 3573, K = 1898, p = 0.5) has a result of a p value of about 0.0002 which is awful and way out of range of what one would expect.
I run this code very early, like didFinishLaunchingWithOptions-early but my impression with current iOS random features was always that the RNG provided by the system and always on track.
But no, the numbers that I see look like they are rather attached to the launch time. It feels like the bias in the distribution stems from different devices being faster/slower to launch and the "randomness" stems from an RNG that's seeded when the app launches instead of a global system RNG - the launch time introducing a great bias towards the second element in the array.
Consequence
Am I reading too much into this? Statistically, at this sample size, I am convinced the results shouldn't look so bad but maybe there is something else I haven't considered? If I am "right" at how I am looking at this and if you know more about randomness in Swift/iOS; what would you suggest me to get closer to 50-50?
Counter-hypothesis locally
To see how the distribution is when ran locally, I have done the following:
let total = 3573
for _ in 0..<total {
    if let coinSide = CoinSide.allCases.randomElement() {
        if(coinSide == .Head) {
            heads += 1
        } else {
            tails += 1
        }
    } else {
        print("Not found")
    }
}

let dTotal = Double(total)/100

print("""
      H: \(heads), T: \(tails), Ratio: \(String(format: "%.2f", Double(heads)/dTotal)):\(String(format: "%.2f", Double(tails)/dTotal))
      """)

This, when tapped on a button, gives:
H: 1802, T: 1771, Ratio: 50.43:49.57
H: 1761, T: 1812, Ratio: 49.29:50.71
H: 1752, T: 1821, Ratio: 49.03:50.97

and even when put in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions on Release configuration I get even results:
H: 1745, T: 1828, Ratio: 48.84:51.16
H: 1831, T: 1742, Ratio: 51.25:48.75
H: 1797, T: 1776, Ratio: 50.29:49.71

What I haven't tried yet is how it would perform when being launched 3573 times (not sure how I would automate that) but it's probably not useful to know anyways because it's flawed in production regardless
Now why are the results so different in production across devices and what can I do against that? I don't think the sample size of 3573 is too small to have this more than ~6% bias in production at this point?

The default generator is optimized for performance, not uniformity/security. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/systemrandomnumbergenerator You can use Array.randomElement(using:) to pass your own implementation of RandomNumberGenerator, but you'll have to find (or implement) a uniform one, there doesn't appear to be one built into the standard library

@Alexander thank you for your comment. You're saying that there is not uniform one provided, but wouldn't the SecRandomCopyBytes for example do that, since Apple says this one is cryptographically secure? Or maybe the GKRandomDistribution?

They would, but that’s not what backs it under the hood. See the link I sent, which shows that it uses arc4random on Apple platforms. On Linux it’s different, and perhaps that backend isn’t uniform.

Maybe I phrased it weirdly but the results are 100% from iOS, not server-side Swift Linux. I'm not sure if I understood your other phrase; on iOS do you reckon SecRandomCopyBytes/GKRandomDistribution would have better results than the default .randomElement? If so, do you by any chance know what's better? It's so hard to find data on that

Ohhh idk why but I interpreted "in production" as as "server-side" haha. Do you understand my first comment, about using Array.randomElement(using:) to draw a random element from your array, using a custom random number generator that you provide yourself?

Haha no worries, yes I got that part but what I don't get is what number generator to use instead. I cannot find any statistical data on what distribution I can expect from iOS internal's (or other) random number generators so what I'm asking is whether you know whether SecRandomCopyBytes/GKRandomDistribution/whatever would give better results for my use case which is drawing a number very early in on the app launch

I don’t know those two compare, but you can use either of them to be the backing implementation of your own RNG type. I would try both and compare
